# Filtering a tuple while preserving order in TLA+

Tags: tla+

I'm working on modelling a primary-backup protocol in TLA+, and have the replication configuration in a tuple. Some setup TLA+:

```
NNodes == 3
Nodes == 1..NNodes
```

Then, in a Pluscal algorithm:

```
config = << 1, 2, 3 >>;
healthy = [ n \in Nodes |-> TRUE ];
```

I have a *process* which sets the values in *healthy* to FALSE, and want another process which removes the entries from *config* based on whether healthy is FALSE while preserving the order of the remaining entries in *config*.

If *config* was a set, removing the unhealthy entries would trivial, but I'm looking for a good way to do that with a tuple. I can use *Append* in a loop, but that causes a lot of extra states for TLC to deal with. Any better ways in TLA+ or Pluscal?

Ideally the solution wouldn't assume that the entries in config start off in sorted order, but I could work around that limitation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Sequences` module contains the `SelectSeq` operator, which solves your exact use case. It will look something like

```
SelectSeq(config, LAMBDA x: healthy[x])
```

See page 341 of *Specifying Systems*.

Answer (score 0):

Does the order of config elements matter? Otherwise I'd propose to replace it with a set `config = {1,2,3}`. You can easily filter the set as set difference `config \ {2}`.

Comment: Yes, order does matter. I've been trying to figure our how to filter the tuple as a set, then re-order according to the order in the original tuple, but can't find a method that doesn't make TLC sad.